# Running Excel Macro On Hyperlink Click

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink, macros

I'm trying to assign macros to hyperlinks I have set up in excel. I have the hyperlinks linking back to the same cell that contains the hyperlink. Based on code examples I've found I've come up with this code block:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)

Select Case Target.Range.Address

Case "$B$3"
     MsgBox ("Test")
Case "$Z$3"
     MsgBox ("Test")
Case Else
    Exit Sub
End Select

End Sub
```

Nothing is happening when I click either hyperlink. I have tried running `Application.EnableEvents = True` as well and still can't get anything to fire. Also, I have verified the code block is set in the correct worksheet module. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: Here is a screencap of the hyperlink dialog as an example for the hyperlinks I have set up:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/QwHuXJJ.jpg]

I have tried both "Z3" and $Z$3 for the address (both ways direct me to the cell properly, it just doesn't fire the macro.)

Comment: have you tried to use `Target.SubAddress`?

Comment: Just tried it. Macro still doesn't run.

Comment: if there is just a `Debug.Print "OK"` did it trigger?

Comment: just `Debug.Print "Ok"` doesn't do anything, but if I put only `MsgBox ("Test")` in the Worksheet_FollowHyperlink event it does work. Also, if I put a call to one of my macros it will trigger. However, I need to be able to call different macros based on different hyperlinks. I tried If statements instead of a Select Case and it doesn't worth that way either.

Comment: what does `MsgBox ("Target.SubAddress")` tell you? Or what does `MsgBox ("Target.Range.Address")` show you?

Comment: Good plan, my man! Target.SubAddress showed "Sheet1!Z3"... I changed my Select Case to `Target.SubAddress` and my Cases to `Case "Sheet1!Z3"` and `Case "Sheet1!B3` respectively and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code works **if the code is in the worksheet code area**

Right-click the tab at the bottom and:

[image]

Comment: I have to code in the correct worksheet code area. The only difference I see is that I don't have the actual address as the text for my hyperlink. Could that be the issue? Preferably, I would like to keep the text descriptive to what the macro will do...

Comment: @SincereApathy  The text is not important..............another reason the macro may not be called is if you are using the *=HYERLINK()* worksheet function rather than an Inserted hyperlink in the cell.

Comment: Still no luck. Thanks you for your time ... must be some other settings/technical issue.

Comment: @SincereApathy the problem is not with your code....it runs on my system.......perhaps the problem is with the hyperlink ??

Comment: I have edited my post to show how I set up the hyperlink.

Comment: What can I do when =HYERLINK() is used?